# Mediawiki: Installing the Popups Extension

Tags: popup, mediawiki

Absolutely losing my mind about why [this](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Popups) doesn't work. I'm running Mediawiki 1.33.1 with PHP 7.2.34 and MySQL 5.6.51-cll-lve; installed version 1.31 of Popups and its dependencies as the 1.35 and master versions throw up expected incompatibility errors.

All three extensions (PageImages, Popups, and TextExtracts) installed successfully and appear on [the Version page](http://gothambynight.com/DCWiki/index.php/Special:Version). However, absolutely no pop-ups are appearing for either logged-in users or casual visitors. Here's my LocalSettings code:

```
wfLoadExtension('TextExtracts');
wfLoadExtension('PageImages');
wfLoadExtension('Popups');

$wgPopupsOptInDefaultState = '1';
$wgPopupsOptInStateForNewAccounts = '1';
$wgPopupsHideOptInOnPreferencesPage = true;
$wgPopupsReferencePreviewsBetaFeature = false;
```

With opt-in set to default so that it SHOULD work for all users and visitors, with no option to disable.

I've dug through all the bug reports in the Talk page and spent the morning googling, but it doesn't seem to be a cache issue (tried clearing and testing, nothing) and I'm not getting any messages via debugging. I'm not running any of the other extensions mentioned as potential conflicts - the only other extensions being loaded are CategoryTree, InputBox, and WikiEditor, and disabling them has no effect.

Comment: Try Ctrl+F5 in your browser to purge the browser cache.

Comment: Already done, unfortunately just as much no effect. (Getting the same lack of response in both Firefox and Chrome, incidentally, and on multiple boxes.)